# how to run spider multiple times with different input

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to scrape information from different sites about some products. Here is the structure of my program:

```
product_list = [iPad, iPhone, AirPods, ...]

def spider_tmall:
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('searchKeywords').send_keys(inputlist[a])

# ...


def spider_jd:
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('searchKeywords').send_keys(inputlist[a])

# ...

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for a in range(len(inputlist)):
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
            "FEEDS": {
                "itemtmall.csv": {"format": "csv",
                                  'fields': ['product_name_tmall', 'product_price_tmall', 'product_discount_tmall'], },
                "itemjd.csv": {"format": "csv",
                               'fields': ['product_name_jd', 'product_price_jd', 'product_discount_jd'], },
        })

        process.crawl(tmallSpider)
        process.crawl(jdSpider)
        process.start()
```

Basically, I want to run all spiders for all inputs in `product_list`. Right now, my program only runs through all spiders once (in the case, it does the job for iPad) then there is `ReactorNotRestartable` Error and the program terminates. Anybody knows how to fix it?
Also, my overall goal is to run the spider multiple times, the input doesn't necessarily have to be a list. It can be a CSV file or something else. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

When you call `process.start()` Scrapy's `CrawlerProcess` will start a Twisted reactor that by default will stop when the crawlers are finished and it's not supposed to be restarted. One possible solution you can try is executing with `stop_after_crawl` [param](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.start) set to `False`:

```
 process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
```

This will prevent the reactor to stop, bypassing the restart problem. Although I can't say it won't lead to other problems further, so you should test it to be sure.

In the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process) there is also an example to running multiple spiders in the same process, one of which actively runs/stops the reactor, but it uses `CrawlerRunner` instead of `CrawlerProcess`.

Finally, if the solutions above don't help, I would suggest trying this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        "FEEDS": {
            "itemtmall.csv": {"format": "csv",
                              'fields': ['product_name_tmall', 'product_price_tmall', 'product_discount_tmall'], },
            "itemjd.csv": {"format": "csv",
                           'fields': ['product_name_jd', 'product_price_jd', 'product_discount_jd'], },
    })
    for a in range(len(inputlist)):
        process.crawl(tmallSpider)
        process.crawl(jdSpider)
    process.start()
```

The point here is that the process is started only once outside the loop, and the `CrawlerProcess` **instantiation is also outside the loop**, otherwise every iteration would overwrite the previous instance of the `CrawlerProcess`.

Answer (score 1):

The process should be started after all of the spiders are set up like it can be seen here:

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process

In your case scenario, a little bit more of code would've helped but I suppose that setting up all the crawl processes for both of the spiders for all of the prodcts and then firing up the `start()` function.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    for a in range(len(inputlist)):
        process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
            "FEEDS": {
                "itemtmall.csv": {"format": "csv",
                                  'fields': ['product_name_tmall', 'product_price_tmall', 'product_discount_tmall'], },
                "itemjd.csv": {"format": "csv",
                               'fields': ['product_name_jd', 'product_price_jd', 'product_discount_jd'], },
        })

        process.crawl(tmallSpider)
        process.crawl(jdSpider)
    process.start()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this with inputlist = [iPhone, iPad]. No error is throwed and the program is able to finish. However, the program ran the spider with "iPad" as the input twice, instead of iPhone and then iPad. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure, are you setting up the variables correctly while spawning the spider? On the provided code the "a" variable is unused entirely and that is the reference.
You can pass parameters to the spiders and then construct the urls and crawling from there, like this example:
`process.crawl(spider, input='inputargument', first='James', last='Bond')`

Answer (score 0):

Using class that should be easy,
there are few things to notice when using `scrapy.Request`

`callback` is a method that handles response

`dont_filter=True` allows you to request same pages multiple times

`errback` is a method that handles responses with errors

you can yield `Request` anytime and it will be added to the pool

```
import scrapy

class GSMArenaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "smartmania"
    main_url = ['https://smartmania.cz/zarizeni/telefony/']  # you can put as many starting links as you want
    

    def start_requests(self):        
        for url in GSMArenaSpider.main_url:
            self.my_logger.debug(f"Starting Scrapy @ {url}")
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_pages, errback=self.errback_httpbin)  # You can bind any parsing method you need
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_ipads, errback=self.errback_httpbin)  # You can bind any parsing method you need
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_iphones, errback=self.errback_httpbin)  # You can bind any parsing method you need

    def parse_pages(self, response):
        # parsing results
        #
        for url in result:
            self.my_logger.info(f"Found pages: {url}")
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_phone_links, errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                                 dont_filter=True)

            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_pages, errback=self.errback_httpbin, dont_filter=False)  # Be careful when doing recursion requests and not using filter

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        """ Handling Errors """
        url = failure.request.url
        callback = failure.request.callback
        errback = failure.request.errback  # should work same way as callback... ?
        status = failure.value.response.status
        self.my_logger.error(f"Fail status: {status} @: {url}")
```